# Structural Equation Models: Tracing rule for error terms

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

Below is a graph together with my best guess for the system of equations resulting from (Wright’s) path decomposition underlying SEM. $cov_{obs}$ is the observed/sample covariance and $\beta$ and $\gamma$ refer to the true/population covariance we want to estimate. 
[image]

My question is what to do with the free covariance $\gamma_2$ of the error/disturbance terms $D$. Or more concrete, why is $X_1$ -> $Y_1$ <- $D_1$ <-> $D_2$ -> $Y_2$ of strength $\beta_1\gamma_2$ not a path to explain $cov_{obs}(X,Y)$ according to the path decomposition rule that 'no ingoing arrow should follow an outgoing arrow'? Or should it be? Has it something to do with colliders also for disturbance terms?

Comment: I think you are asking if the disturbance $D_1$ is a random variable like any other, and the answer is yes. $Y_1$ is a collider on that path.

Comment: Thanks Alvaro for mentioning that $D_1$ is a variable like very other. I didn't quite realise that yet. Though the problem with the collider theory is the following: There is (typically) a joint causal variable $C$ which has a causal impact on both $D_1$ and $D_2$. Thus the indirect path from $Y_2$ to $Y_1$ is $Y_2$ <- $D_2$ <- $C$ -> $D_1$ -> $Y_1$ but that is just a backdoor rather than a forward path and $Y_1$ would not be a collider for the path $X_1$ -> $Y_1$ -> $Y_2$. That is because $Y_2$ does not cause $Y_1$ in any way.

Comment: Another theory, I just came up with is that $X_1$ already identifies $Y_1$. Thus, the correlation between $Y_1\hat=\beta_0+\beta_1X_1$ and the confounder $C$ is actually 0. And that is why $X_1$ -> $Y_1$ <- $D_1$ <- $C$ -> $D_2$ -> $Y_2$ is no correlation path. Could that work as an explanation?